# trying to work out the bugs in a simple email form - Still learning php

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the bug in my email code for a site. This is a form to make reservations, but I cant get it to send the info once filled out. Im still new to PHP so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you ahead of time.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$err = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){        

    $first = addslashes(trim($_POST['first'])); 

    $last = addslashes(trim($_POST['last']));   

    $email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));

    $date = addslashes(trim($_POST['date']));

    $women = addslashes(trim($_POST['women']));

    $men = addslashes(trim($_POST['men']));

            $message = "Name: $name" . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= "Phone: $phone" . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= "Email: $email" . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= "Date: $date" . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= "Women: $women" . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= "Men: $men" . PHP_EOL;

            $header = "From: reservations@bryanlv.com";

            mail("sales@pinnaclewebsitedesigns.com", "New Club Reservation", $message, $header);

            header('location:thank-you.html');      

        } else {    

        if($name=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your Name is empty</p>';  

        if($phone=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your Phone is empty</p>';    

        if($email=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your E-mail is empty</p>';   

        if($date=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your Reservation Date is empty</p>';  

        if($women=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Number of Women is empty</p>';

        if($men=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Number of Men is empty</p>';

    }
```

?>

And here is the form:

```
<form name="reservation" method="post" action="book.php">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" />
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone" />
                    <label>E-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="email" />
                    <label>Date of Reservation </label>
                    <input type="date" name="date" id="date"  placeholder="date" />
                    <label>Number of Women </label>
                    <input type="text" name="women" id="women"  placeholder="women" />
                    <label>Number of Men </label>
                    <input type="text" name="men" id="men"  placeholder="men" />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Book now</button>
                 </form>
```

I know it has to be something simple Im missing.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No error... goes through, but nothing come to the email and doesn't go to thank you page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

But there's no form element with the `submit` name and hence it fails to suffice the if condition, you can try replacing this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Book now</button>
```

with

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Book now" />
```

Answer (score 2):

drop the if statement or add a

```
 <input type=hidden name="submit" value ='1'>
```

to your form

Just a little info php POST is taking the name from the forms and retrieving the value. Your form did not have a element with the name submit therefore when you post it it returns false...you then used an if isset() which it wasnt and therefore no code executed. If your stuck in the future add an else to your if statement and echo 'fail'

Comment: Why you need to set a hidden field for that if you can simply assign that name to the submit button itself

Comment: +1 good catch .... another option would be to test $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"

Comment: because its the first thing that came to mind and I knew someone would beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple.

Use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {` to test if the user is posting the form.

I did a quick run of the form and the output was:

`Array ( [name] => [phone] => [email] => [date] => [women] => [men] => )`

Nothing related about the button, and that's a bad way to check anyway.

Simply change:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

to:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
```

I would still highly go against using the name of the submit button.

Please make a system like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="type_of_post" value="register / login / what type of action">
```

Comment: Well, dave, this will be risky if OP has 2 forms with `POST` so better use a unique identifier rather than using general `REQUEST METHOD` check :)

Comment: I agree, I recall certain browsers (ie), the submit button does not work as expected. I would recommend putting a hidden type that states what the form is supposed to do. This also helps with what type of data the server is supposed to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are using $name variable but I don't see that setup in your php file.

Other than that please provide the error message - either from on the screen or from your apache logs (if you use apache of course)